# Maximum order of MCG finite order elements

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Given an orientable compact  surface S  with genus g b and b boundary components and p punctures, is there a maximun order of finite order elements in the mapping class group of S? If yes is there a formula to determine it?

Comment: Yes: as a group of automorphisms of some variety in char 0, the mapping class group is virtually torsion-free and hence there is a bound on the order of its finite subgroups. The precise bound might depend on some details (e.g., whether you all orientation-reversing elements in MCG). It is also natural to ask about multiplicative bounds (e.g. statements of the form: finite orders of elements should divide some given number, or some number among a small list), and in particular exclude cyclic group of large enough prime order (much below the largest possible order).

Comment: That MCGs are virtually torsion-free is certainly proved in Farb--Margalit somewhere. For a crude upper bound, at least in the non-closed case, one can use the fact that the natural map to $Sp(n,\mathbb{Z}/3)$ is known to have torsion-free kernel; so the order of torsion is bounded by the maximal order of an element in $Sp(n,\mathbb{Z}/3)$. (Apparently this fact is proved in a 1968 paper by Baumslag and Taylor.)

Comment: On reflection, that they're virtually torsion-free also follows immediately from Nielsen realisation. In particular, any finite subgroup is necessarily of order at most 42(2g-2) in the closed case (since this is the degree of a covering map to the minimum-area 2d orbifold).

Comment: @HJRW also it yields a bound in the non-closed case (since one can "close" the surface gluing pairwise the boundary components and closing the possible last one with a 1-punctured torus). (This works at least if the realization problem can be solved with a group of self-homeomorphisms acting as identity on the boundary). On the other hand,  I can see why this provides a bound on the order of finite subgroups, but why does this imply virtual torsion-freeness?

Comment: @YCor, you're right: I guess I was implicitly using a couple of other related facts (only finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups, and residual finiteness).

Answer (score 2):

The answers to all the questions can be found in that fond of wisdom Farb-Margalit:

*Farb, Benson; Margalit, Dan*, A primer on mapping class groups, Princeton Mathematical Series. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press (ISBN 978-0-691-14794-9/hbk; 978-1-400-83904-9/ebook). xiv, 492 p. (2011). [ZBL1245.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1245.57002).

To be precise, in Chapter 7, they note that if $b>0,$ then there the mapping class group is torsion free, while for a closed surface, the maximal order of an element is $4g + 2.$ The latter uses Nielsen realization, not surprisingly.

*EDIT* As Dan points out in the comments, you lose torsion only if you have boundary components which you wish to preserve pointwise. Punctures keep the number at $4g+2.$

Comment: By the way, if you have a surface of genus g > 1 and p punctures, then the maximum order is still 4g+2 since a finite order homeomorphism of the punctured surface induces a finite order homeomorphism of the closed surface, with the same order.  (And thanks!)

Comment: @DanMargalit Corrected, thanks! The book is amazing, thanks!